# Sum of incoming weights in probabilistic system sum to 1

Tags: dynamical-systems, quantum-computation

In Yanofsky and Mannucci's *Quantum Computing for Computer Scientists*, page 80, it is said, when referring to a probabilistic dynamical system modeled by a (finite) graph, that

> We shall restrict our attention to weighted graphs that satisfy the
>   following two conditions: a) the sum of all the weights leaving a
>   vertex is 1 and b) the sum of all the weights entering a vertex is 1.
>   This will correspond to the fact that the marble must both go and come
>   from someplace (there might be loops).

I understand why the fact that the marbles must go someplace requires condition a), but I don't understand why b) is required for the marbles to come from (or go) someplace.

**Why is b) necessary for the marble to come from (or go) someplace?**

Happy to provide more detail on my thoughts, if necessary or desired.

¡Besos, matematicos!

Comment: I'd say you're right in being puzzled, that it's a poor (even wrong) explanation. Any valid transition matrix leads to a dynamical system where "the marble must both go and come from someplace" - only the condition $a)$ is required. The aditional condition $b$ (which corresponds to a doubly stochastic matrix) is actually very restrictive (and, for irreducible chains leads to equiprobable stationary states) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37731/why-does-a-finite-irreducible-and-aperiodic-markov-chain-with-a-doubly-stochast

Comment: The cited explanation is poor indeed. I guess what really leads to requiring both conditions (and consequently doubly stochastic transition matrices) is that quantum systems are restrained by unitarity, and a doubly stochastic matrix satisfies that. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0608206.pdf for some very pointed arguments. Further, reversibility may be a requirement which again is satisfied by a doubly stochastic matrix. Yet another requirement which is satisfied is detailed balance.

Comment: Agree with @Andreas. Quantum processes have to be information-preserving, hence reversible. Therefore the reverse process has to be stochastic too.